# Guardar contenido de un checkbox de HTML en MySql mediante PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Soy nuevo usando PHP y HTML. Estoy utilizando Xampp, donde tengo una base de datos de normbre "prueba", con una tabla de nombre "tabla" y con un solo atributo de tipo boolean llamado "aceptado". El problema que tengo es que al intentar ejecutar el código php al realizar el formulario HTML, en lugar de ejecutar el código el navegador me abre el archivo php.

Este es mi .php:

```
<?php

    //Conectar con el servidor
    $conectar = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("No se pudo conectar con el servidor");
    //Verificar la conexion

        $bd = mysql_select_db('prueba', $conectar) or die ("No se encontro la Base de Datos");

    //Recuperar variables
    $aceptado = "$_POST['aceptado']";
    $bool = isset($aceptado);
    //Hacer la sentencia
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla VALUES ('$bool')";
    //Ejecutar la sentencia".
    $ejecutar = mysql_query($sql, $conectar);

    if(!$ejecutar)
    {
        echo "ERROR al ejecutar";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Datos guardados correctamente <br> <a href = 'single-colummn.html'>Volver </a>";
    }

?>
```

Y esta es la parte de código del formulario HTML con la que quiero ejecutar esto:

```
<form action = "guardar.php" method = "POST">

        <p>Aceptado<input type="checkbox" name="aceptado" value="1" /></center></p>
```

Comment: Suena a que no lo estas ejecutando en el servidor si no abriendolo directamente.

Comment: Con Xampp le he dado a Start a Apache y a MySQL y he abierto phpadmin en el navegador mientras abro el formulario también en el navegador ¿Debo hacer algo más?

Comment: Hola, has colocado en tu navegador `http://localhost/` ? o en que forma abriste el formulario?

Comment: Si estás empezando, como dices, lo primero es que aprendas basándote en código actualizado. Las funciones de tipo `mysql_connect` son **obsoletas** actualmente. Si usas PHP 7 tu código no funcionará nunca, y si usas PHP 5, tu código es vulnerable. Algo esencial, sobre todo al principio, es saber de qué  fuente estás aprendiendo a programar. En el caso de PHP hay demasiado código viejo que se perpetúa de generación en generación.

Comment: Ademas de lo que te dijeron en el comentario anterior, si estas empezando a programar en php y mysql te recomiendo usar un framework (como codeigniter), este te ayuda mucho en la parte de conexiones a base de datos y te evita muchos problemas.

Comment: Respondiendo a  the-breaker, no, lo he abierto simplemente abriendo el archivo con el navegador ¿Qué debo hacer exactamente para abrirlo con  localhost?

Comment: En cuanto al resto de comentarios, ¿Qué framework es el más adecuado?

Comment: El framework más popular pero con una curva de aprendizaje algo alta es Laravel: Sería bueno que tomes en cuenta el framework que sugirió @the-breaker porque posee una curva de aprendizaje más accesible cuando estás empezando a manejar frameworks en general, luego te cambias a symfony, laravel, yii o aquel de tu preferencia.

Comment: El usar un framework como te recomienda @the-breaker evitará en buena medida que adquieras malas prácticas que son comúnes (y no perceptibles en principio) cuando se está aprendiendo PHP debido a que este lenguaje es "muy permisivo" a la hora de programar.

Comment: @pepito, para abrir el proyecto y que se ejecuten las sentencias php este debe pasar por un cgi, para esto debes tener tu proyecto en una carpeta dentro la carpeta `htdocs` que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `xampp` (donde lo instalaste), luego para acceder debes colocar `http://localhost/myproyecto` en tu navegador, donde `miproyecto` es el nombre de la carpeta en la que tienes tu proyecto. Para terminar el framework mas adecuado para trabajar es [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.es/) por la gran cantidad de documentación (en español) y guías super didácticas. Saludos.